# Clone a resource group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

So, I've setup a lab environment in a azure resource group with a domain controller, sql-server and a web server. I would like to clone that whole resource group to a new one when needed and by stat I mean with everything intact. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of anyway to do a direct copy, but you can export a JSON template from the portal or PowerShell that will come close to giving you something you can automate.  I say "close" because the feature is still in preview and some resources can't be exported.

In portal.azure.com go to:
Resource Groups > [your rg] > Settings > Export...

In PowerShell see:

```
Export-AzureRMResourceGroup
```

Comment: I already tried the whole export template thing but the domain controller was empty so to speak

Comment: Do you mean it was just an empty VM?  One of the known limitations at the moment is that VM extensions aren't exported...

Comment: What I mean is that I had a domain controller, dns and so on installed on the template server but the one that got installed from the template export did not have that.

Comment: Ok, that's precisely it... those configurations are generally done by "in guest customization" or extensions (custom script, DSC).  The VMs are exported but their configuration is not yet part of the exported JSON.

Comment: Still worked fine for me 10/2022 :-)

Answer (score 6):

So, the solution I came up with was to simply creating a new Resource group, copy the template (not sysprepped) vhds to that new Resource group and creating new VMs with the vhd's attached.

I do wish that there was a "Clone resource group" button somewhere :)

Answer (score 1):

To clone a resource group
1. Go to: Resource groups > [resource group to copy] > Settings (sidebar grouping) > Export template > Deploy

My resource group:
[image]

Issues on my way with solutions:

1. Parameter osDisk.managedDisk.id is not allowed

   - 'Edit Template' button
   - Remove id field under osDisk.managedDisk
   - See: [osDisk.managedDisk.id’ is not allowed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/05/16/osdisk-manageddisk-id-is-not-allowed/)
2. Disk [disk subscription] cannot be attached as the disk is already owned by VM [VM subscription]

   - Make the data disk snapshot
   - Create a new disk based on the snapshot (important: the disk name cannot be changed)
   - Change proper id parameter value in settings or edit parameters (under 'Edit parameters' button)
3. Changing property 'dataDisk.name' is not allowed.

   - As mentioned above. Do not change the disk name when coping the disk.
4. Required parameter 'adminPassword' is missing (null)."

   - 'Edit Parameters'
   - Add:

     ```
     "adminPassword": {
         "value": null
     }
     ```
   - 'Edit Template'
   - Add:

     ```
     "adminPassword": {
         "defaultValue": null,
         "type": "SecureString"
     }
     ```
   - Set the adminPassword in settings

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Jeff Bow's scripts to copy / clone a resource group](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azuregov/copying-azure-resource-groups-between-different-azure-subscriptions-or-environments/):

- [Copy-AzureRMresourceGroup.ps1](https://github.com/JeffBow/AzurePowerShell/blob/master/Copy-AzureRMresourceGroup.ps1)

> Copies Azure V2 (ARM) resources from one Azure Subscription to
> another.
>
> Unlike the Move-AzureRMresource cmdlet, this script allows
> you to move between subscriptions in different Tenants and different
> Azure Environments. Requires AzureRM module version 6.7 or later.

- [Clone-AzureRMresourceGroup.ps1](https://github.com/JeffBow/AzurePowerShell/blob/master/Clone-AzureRMresourceGroup.ps1)

> Clones Azure V2 (ARM) resources from one resource group into a new
> resource group in the same Azure Subscriptions.
>
> Requires AzureRM module version 6.7 or later.
>
> This is intended mostly for Azure V2 virtual machines and will include
> copying virtual disks, virtual network, load balancers, Public IPs and
> other associated storage accounts, blob files and now managed disks.

PS suggest you upvote this Azure feedback to provide an Azure-native command, [Copy resource groups](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/14142671-copy-resource-groups):

- https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/14142671-copy-resource-groups

Comment: Do these work as of today 2021-05-11? I have previously used of those (can't remember which one), but now I get an error from both saying "Get-AzureRmResourceGroup – Provided resource group does not exist".

Comment: Have not used lately, check out the author's git repo, https://github.com/JeffBow/AzurePowerShell. It shows no commits in over 2 years, perhaps there is an MS Azure API change that broke the underlying code. You could log an issue with the author, or if you have the dev skills, clone his repo and troubleshoot the code. There's another issue with community reply indicating that it is very easy to tweak the PS cmdlet source code to the Az modules.

Comment: I saw that JeffBow posted his solution himself, but the reactions weren't friendly. Had SO been more welcoming and accepting him, and people are still able to see and interreact with him, the outcome might be a different story.

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't look to be specifically designed for this use case, I have successfully moved RGs using [Azure Resource Mover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/overview), released in 2021.  Since it isn't mandatory to remove any resources from the source RG, this has worked better for me than exporting the RG JSON and redeploying, etc.